# union on same collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need the most viable way to search docs with the following structure.

```
{ _id:"",
var1: number,
var2: number,
var3: number,
}
```

In the sql way the resultset i need would be UNION of these three (n records sorted by var1,n records sorted by var2,n records sorted by var3)

with UNION I expect the duplicates to be removed.

Being new to mongodb i am not able to find the right way to write a query for such an operation, i believe it must be possible in mongodb.

> If in case its not possible, could you please suggest an alternate nosql solution.

Answer (score 8):

The closest MongoDB operator to what you are looking for is an [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/), but that isn't quite the same as an [SQL UNION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator) which combines two separate queries into a single result.  MongoDB queries are always against a single collection, but `$or` allows you to have multiple query clauses.

For example:

```
db.collection.find(
    // Find documents matching any of these values
    {$or:[
        {var1: 123},
        {var2: 456},
        {var3: 789}
    ]}
).sort(
    // Sort in ascending order
    {var1:1, var2:1, var3:1}
)
```

Since you are limited to querying a single collection, results will already be de-duplicated at the document level and all results will share the same sort order if one is specified.

If you want to simulate a UNION (or other operation working with multiple collections/queries) in MongoDB, you will have to write multiple queries and merge the result sets in your application code.

Comment: The problem is sorting and limits. I need only first n records from each set. Anyways i don't think its possible in mongodb I'll do it via multiple queries.

I have another query regarding the sort you wrote, will {var1:-1, var2:-1, var3:-1} mean that the results would be ordered considering all the three as one. 
    A = {"var1":3,"var2":8,"var3":11}
    B = {"var1":4,"var2":6,"var3":9}
    C = {"var1":4,"var2":7,"var3":2}

will results in A(var3=11),B(var3=9),C(var2=7) or C(var2=7),B(var2=6),A(var1=3)

Comment: Yes .. if you want to sample from each query you will have to do multiple queries and merge the results in your code.  For sort orders the easiest way to compare would be to try an example in the shell :). Your spec using fields with "-1" would sort in descending order for that field (1 for ascending).