# Union query in mongodb without using map/reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, union

How can I convert the following SQL query for mongo:

```sql
SELECT column1 from table1
UNION
SELECT column1 from table2
```

I have up to 12 collections, one for each month:

```
data.2013.01
data.2013.02
...
...
data.2013.12
```

When plotting I'd like to show multiple months on graph at a time. That brings us to the question, how to create UNION in mongo.

Comment: do you know about aggregation framework?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I'm new to mongo, checking now. Do you know what could work?

Comment: I checked the aggregation framework. It has pipeline and operators like $group. However they still all work on single collection only. Suggestions?

Comment: you could create temp collection with data from other collections and after plot the graph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the ultimate conclusion you will come to is that your schema is incorrect. Put all your objects of the same purpose and shape into a single collection. That's how to work in harmony with mongodb. Making collections by month is a mistake that will cause you endless needless battles with mongo. Once you have everything in one collection as intended, the aggregation can handle grouping by month for you as per the [aggregation example of usernames ordered by join month](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/#return-usernames-ordered-by-join-month).

Comment: I see your point, and I think it is valid for example in the link you provided. However my application is _similar_ to web analytics, though for different purpose and it tracks different numbers. Each collection will have aggregate data for month and each document will have aggregate data for a day and embedded documents for each hour of day. Organizing data like this will make reads very fast. For a months worth of data I'll only be querying 30 documents compared to thousands if I go with the sample you provided. As I mentioned the approach in link might work for other scenarios.

Comment: Seems, me being new to mongo and still figuring out functionality for the application made me miss your point. I could keep structure of the document same as I have but should put all the documents in one collection. Makes sense. Sorry I didn't got that first time I read your answer. Thanks @Peterlyons

Comment: Keep in mind you can also map/reduce from the main collection to a month-specific collection and get your fast/cached reads. But mongo needs to operate on a single collection which is kind of by definition "whatever you need mongo to run operations on", so that's where your canonical data needs to live.

Answer (score 1):

read this at first:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

mongo does not have something like `union` but i think `$or` will be useful for your needs.

read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14928646/1321404

Comment: I read the documentation and question you suggested. Seems it is not possible to create UNION using multiple collections in mongo. You answer made that clear for me. Will try to solve this on application side.

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the aggregation framework provides a new [`$unionWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/#unionwith-aggregation) stage, performing the union of two collections (the combined pipeline results from two collections into a single result set):

```
// collection1:
//   { "date" : "2013-12-27", "origin" : "collection1" }
//   { "date" : "2017-03-11", "origin" : "collection1" }
// collection2:
//   { "date" : "2014-11-02", "origin" : "collection2" }
db.collection1.aggregate([
  { $unionWith: "collection2" },
  { $project: { date: true } }
])
// { "date" : "2013-12-27" }
// { "date" : "2017-03-11" }
// { "date" : "2014-11-02" }
```

---

Note that you can obtain the same result by first selecting columns and then performing the union (the collection being combined can be applied an aggregation pipeline before the union is performed):

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  { $project: { date: true } },
  { $unionWith: {
      coll: "collection2",
      pipeline: [{ $project: { date: true } }]
  }}
])
```