# What is union in sql in mongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, union

I want `union` result of queries :

```
db.links.aggregate({$unwind:"$comments"},{$project:{ votes:{$subtract:["$comments.upVotes", "$comments.downVotes"]} } }) 

db.links.aggregate({$unwind:"$comments"},{$unwind:"$comments.replies"},{$project:{ votes:{$subtract:["$comments.replies.upVotes", "$comments.replies.downVotes"]} } })
```

but I can't find any answer for this.

Example for `union` in `sql`:

```
(selectcourse_id from section where sem = ‘Fall’ and year = 2009)
union
(selectcourse_id from section where sem = ‘Spring’ and year = 2010)
```

this query return section that are in `( sem = ‘Fall’ and year = 2009)` or `(sem = ‘Spring’ and year = 2010)`

Comment: Could you explain better your questions, please?

Comment: Maybe this post could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924129/union-on-same-collection-in-mongodb

Comment: no. its different between or and union