# Search multiple fields for multiple values in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I've got a MongoDB collection where a particular string may appear in any of a number of fields:

```
{"_id":1, "field1": "foo", "field2": "bar", "field3": "baz", "otherfield": "stuff"},
{"_id":2, "field1": "bar", "field2": "baz", "field3": "foo", "otherfield": "morestuff"},
{"_id":3, "field1": "baz", "field2": "foo", "field3": "bar", "otherfield": "you get the idea"}
```

I need to query so that I am returned all records where any one of a set of fields is equal to any value in an array ... basically, if I have `["foo","bar"]` I need it to match if either of those strings are in field1 or field2 (but not any other field).

Obviously I can do this with a series of multiple queries

`db.collection.find({"field1":{"$in":["foo","bar"]}})`
`db.collection.find({"field2":{"$in":["foo","bar"]}})`

etc., and I've also made a very large $or query that concatenates them all together, but it seems far too inefficient (my actual collection needs to match any of 15 strings that can occur in any of 9 fields) ... but I'm still new to nosql DBs and am not sure of the best paradigm I need to use here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found another answer through poring over the documentation that seems to hit a sweet spot -- text indexes.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"field1":"text","field2":"text"})
db.records.runCommand("text",{search:"foo bar"})
```

When I run my actual query with many more strings and fields (and about 100,000 records), the `$or/$in` approach takes 620 milliseconds while the text index takes 131 milliseconds. The one drawback is that it returns a different type of document as a result; luckily the actual documents are a parameter of each result object.

Thanks to those who took the time to make suggestions.

Answer (score 76):

try

```
db.collection.find(
    // Find documents matching any of these values
    {$or:[
        {"field1":{"$in":["foo","bar"]}},
        {"field2":{"$in":["foo","bar"]}}
    ]}
)
```

also refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924129/union-on-same-collection-in-mongodb)

Comment: jlmcdonald has said that he tried to concatenate the queries to a large $or query...

Comment: Right ... and this works, but there's got to be a more efficient way than this.

Comment: you mean by efficient... an efficient way to write it ... or an efficient way that mongo executes that query...

Comment: That's a good question ... as I mentioned, I've got 15 strings in any of 9 fields, so it makes for a pretty ugly looking $or query when written, so having something more readable would be a small benefit. But my biggest concern is with the expense on the DB. I'm assuming that a concatenated $or query is performing each query and then aggregating results but maybe that's wrong and $or isn't terribly expensive?

Comment: as for the looking i don't know a better way for the query to look better... but as for the expense to the database all of this join/filter/union queries used inside the `find` are called `Criteria` and this criteria is lazy loaded.. so the `find` bigger query only hits the database **once** returning a cursor... so there is no worry about the performance... also if you want the query **not to hit the database at all**... use `where` instead of `find` this way you can get the `Criteria` ... without hitting the db... and you can evaluate the returned criteria when needed (this will hit the db)

Comment: so in other words... the `$or` and `$in` are not as expensive as you think... as far as i know :D

Comment: Does $in need to be quoted?

Comment: Thanks for this answer it works. But there is a bug in the code specifically for Javascirpt. Additionally you have to specify $nin to not check for undefined. Ex:  { "field1" : { "$in" : [ "foo" , "bar" ], $nin : [ undefined ]  }}

Answer (score 0):

I would collect all the relevant fields in one field (i.e. `collected`) by adding their values like

```
"foo:field1", 
"bar:field2", 
"baz:field3",  
"stuff:otherfield", 
"bar:field1", 
"baz:field2"
...
```

into that field.

If you search for `bar` existing in any field you can use:

```
db.collection.find( { collected: { $regex: "^bar" } }, ... );
```

Your example in the question would look like:

```
db.collection.find( collected: { { $all: [ "foo:field1", "foo:field2", "bar:field1", "bar:field2" ] } }, ... );
```