# How to get the rows extracted if few columns are blank or empty

Tags: python, pymongo

I am new to this and would need some help in extracting the records/row only when few columns are blank. Below code is ignoring the blank records and getting me the ones with value. Can someone suggest here ?

```
mongo_docs = mongo.db.user.find({"$and":[{"Param1": {"$ne":None}}, {"Param1": {"$ne": ""}}]})
```

[image: Sample data with expected output]

Comment: Please provide us with a bit more information such as entry data and expected output

Comment: Attached the input and expected out as part of original post in the picture. As of now i am getting all the records as response instead of fetching only the null ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you are using contains `ne` which stands for not-equal. You can change that to `eq` (equals) and check if you get the desired results.

```
mongo_docs = mongo.db.user.find({"$or":[{"Param1": {"$eq":None}}, {"Param1": {"$eq": ""}}]})
```

A simplification of the above code will also be:

```
mongo_docs = mongo.db.user.find({"$or":[{"Param1": {"$eq":None, "$eq": ""}}]})
```

You can also use the [exists query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) if that better satisfies your requirement.

From the comments: You are absolutely right, the command will work with multiple parameters.

```
mongo_docs = mongo.db.user.find({"$or":[{"Param1": {"$eq":None, "$eq": ""}}, {"Param2": {"$eq":None, "$eq": ""}},{"Param3": {"$eq":None, "$eq": ""}}]})
```

Additionally, if you want to do it over a larger range, you can consider using [text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#std-label-text-index-compound). These will allow you to search all the test fields at once, and the code for the same should look something like this:

```
mongo.db.user.createIndex({Param1: "text", Param2: "text", Param3: "text"})
mongo.db.user.find({$text: {$search: ""}})
```

The above works for text content only, and I have not come across any implementation for integer values yet but cannot see why the same should not work with some minor changes using other [wildcards](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-wildcard/).

References:

1. [Search multiple fields for multiple values in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417711/search-multiple-fields-for-multiple-values-in-mongodb)
2. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/
3. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#std-label-text-index-compound
4. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-wildcard/

Comment: Thank you so much.. I am just learning :-)

Comment: One more thing, if i want to add multiple conditions here, meaning i want to retrieve if any of the columns param1,param2,param3 is blank  can i do this way ? mongo_docs = mongo.db.user.find({"$and":[{"Param1": {"$eq":None, "$eq": ""}}, {"Param2": {"$eq":None, "$eq": ""}},{"Param3": {"$eq":None, "$eq": ""}}]})

Comment: It worked after modifying and to or :-) thank you... i am good now

Comment: That's great @mary! And you are absolutely right, or is the correct operation there. I have also made some modifications to the answer and expanded on the multiple columns query. Hope it helps :)