# Get nearest values outside of query range

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a MongoDB database that stores records that have a timestamp for when they were created and a value. I connect to and query this database using the official C# driver.

A normal use case involves getting all records that are >= startDateTime and <= endDateTime, which is pretty straight forward.

However, there are times where the data points are far enough from the start and end of the period that I would need to interpolate the value at startDateTime and endDateTime. For this I obviously need the last record before startDateTime, and the first record after endDateTime. It's easy to do this with three queries, but I'd like to avoid that to reduce the number of round trips to the database.

Is it possible to achieve this with a single query?

Edit: since I was asked to clarify the use case:

Say I have a sensor that logs temperature every hour. The temperature and timestamp gets stored in a MongoDB collection. Now, I want to plot a graph of the temperatures for yesterday, so I ask for all records that have a timestamp >= 2014.02.04 00:00:00 and timestamp < 2014.02.05 00:00:00

It turns out that this sensor logs at 55 minutes into every hour, so my first data point is 55 minutes into yesterday, and my last data point is 5 minutes away from the end yesterday.

In addition to the 24 values that fall within my time range, I'd like to get the values at 2014.02.03 23:55:00 and at 2014.02.05 00:55:00 so that I can interpolate. This needs to be generalized into getting the last record before the beginning of my period and the first record after the end of my period since I have no way of knowing how often the sensor logs, at which time it logs, or if it's been offline at any point.

Edit2: an abbreviated version of my code as it is today:

```
        //Get last record before the period
        var cursor = collection.Find(
            Query.LT("DateTime", startDateTime)
        );
        cursor.Limit = 1;
        cursor.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("DateTime"));
        //Not shown: getting the record from the cursor and adding it to the collection

        //Getting all records that fall within the specified period
        cursor = collection.Find(
            Query.And(
                Query.GTE("DateTime", startDateTime),
                Query.LTE("DateTime", endDateTime))
        );
        //Not shown: getting the records from the cursor and adding them to the collection

        //Get first record after the period
        cursor = collection.Find(
            Query.GT("DateTime", endDateTime)
        );
        cursor.Limit = 1;
        cursor.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("DateTime"));
        //Not shown: getting the record from the cursor and adding it to the collection
```

Comment: I've never used MongoDB.  In SQL Server you could combine those three queries into one with a couple of UNIONs.  Does MongoDB support UNION or an equivalent?

Comment: Yeah, I'm mostly familiary with SQL as well. Looks like there's an OR operator that can be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924129/union-on-same-collection-in-mongodb

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your use case. Are you saying you are are trying to find which start and end dates to use for use in another query? It might help if you post details of what you are actually doing in your question for clarification.

Comment: I updated the OP with an example that I hope will clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Assuming you have an incrementing ID, the simple solution would be to grab the results within the range, and then grammatically , get the one ahead and one after ...

Comment: I think perhaps the clearest explanation is achieved by showing what you are already doing with 3 queries. That makes it clear to people if there is a more optimal approach

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how often the sensor(s) log AND if there is actually a reading recorded in a timely manner "just outside" the desired 24 hours, then the best approach is to make 3 statements.

Removing one of the two constraints could get you results in less statements.

If you are worried on the 3 requests being "slow", you should work on making the requests perform faster, for example by use of an index.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your approach is looking for an analogue of SQL UNION as is implied in the three query operations. And the operations are clear in this approach:

1. Find all the records within a start of day and end of day range
2. Find the first record that occurs before the start of day range
3. Find the last record that occurs after the end of of day range

While that is clear, it may just be me but I'm failing to see the utility of this approach. From what you write, it seems you are trying to gather 24 points for a chart and that chart will follow a 24 hour period. So it would see that the combined results of the three queries issued would return between at best 26 records and at worst 2 records. Or even possibly one, should there be no record beforehand and depending on when the query was run.

Given that, there are two records that *could* well fall way out of your day range and not be of much utility other than to say there was no activity at hours or days before or after.

I know that this is a no code response, but there is no UNION analogue to do what you are doing, but I can propose that maybe you don't need to do what you are doing.

Going on what I'm seeing and what seems to be the function, I cannot see what is wrong with simply fetching the records less than the end of day + 1 hour and limiting to the last 26, in descending sort order. From there you can make whatever decisions you want as to what data to represent, and we are talking about a very small number of results.

If you really believe you must have the set of results that would be produced from the queries you are running then by all means run the three queries. Again these are small result sets and the timings should be negligible.

Comment: "This needs to be generalized into getting the last record before the beginning of my period and the first record after the end of my period since I have no way of knowing how often the sensor logs, at which time it logs, or if it's been offline at any point." - Maybe I wasn't clear, but the above use case is just one of many possible. There could just as easily be a case where the sensor logs every second, I need to look at all records for half a year, and there happens to be a day-long outage encompassing the start of the period. That's why I need a general solution.