# Mongo query with a complicated sort order

Tags: mongodb-query

I'm pretty new to mongo, and I'm trying to work out how to apply a complicated ordering to the results of a query. I've got a collection of posts that either have a type of 'user' or 'promoted' and they all have a create date. What I need to do is order the list by create date, but ensure that the two most recent promoted posts are at the top of the list regardless of when they were created. I'd prefer to do it all in mongo if possible to work with the existing paging solution.

Finding the top two promoted posts is easy:

db.example.find({ type: "pro" }).sort( { create_dt: 1 } ).limit(2)

But do I then need to do an aggregation of all the remaning posts (excluding the original top two) and somehow join the two sets of results? Or is there some way to dynamically tag the top two promoted posts, and then order the whole list using the tag?

Thanks.

Comment: What about splitting this in two queries? One that looks like the one you mentioned above and one that does the rest with an additional filter to get rid of the two special elements?

Comment: Yeah, like I said I'd like to do it all in one query so the paging stays the same, but I can see your way working if I filter the promoted posts out by their ids after the first query loads them.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. It would appear that I'm suffering from a severe case of post-weekend blindness. Anyway, I sense that this kind of query gets a bit tricky (have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924129/union-on-same-collection-in-mongodb). I might be able to look a bit deeper into that in a couple of hours. I have a feeling it could be possible using some aggregation framework magic - just like you said. ;) A nice challenge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew... That took me a while and indeed the result is not particularly satisfying (yet?). Still, it should work - it certainly did on my test data set which I tried to deduce from your input above. I shall happily explain the individual steps in greater detail upon request. As always with MongoDB aggregations you can get an idea of what's going on by simply reducing the projection stages step by step starting from the end of the query.

```
db.restaurants.aggregate(
  {
    $match: {/* for optimization only: any potentially reasonable filters to speed up the query */}
  },
  {
    $sort:
    {
      "type": 1, // 'promoted' first and then 'user' posts
      "create_dt": -1 // the latest posts first
    }
  },
  {
    $group:
    {
      _id:  "$type", // two groups, one for 'promoted' posts & one for type 'user'
      items: { $push: "$$ROOT" } // remember the entire document
    }
  },
  {
    $project:
    {
      "items":
      {
        $zip: // we use $zip to reduce the number of items per group...
        {
          inputs:
          [
            {
              $cond:
              [
                { $eq: ["$_id", "promoted"] }, // ...depending on the type...
                [1,2], //...to 2 items in the case of 'promoted' type posts
                { $range: [ 1, 100, 1 ] } //...and to 100 items - change if needed - for 'user' type posts
              ]
            }
            ,
            "$items"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  {
    $unwind:
    {
      path: "$items", // first level of unwinds --> we get an array output still from the $zip operation
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:
    {
      path: "$items", // second level of unwinds - we flatten everything to the lowest level
    }
  },
  {
    $match:
    {
      "items": { $type: 3 } // get rid of the index element that got created in the $zip stage, only keep objects
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$items" } // make sure we get a nice list of posts back
  }
)
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks for the effort! Was struggling to find any example of this type of problem, and I haven't seen anything like your solution out there.